# Why VS 2010 Intellisense works only when I install visual assist X?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a really big project where having intellisense would be more than helpful, but I am not able to make it works.  I went [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235519%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to try to resolve my problem, but not luck.

I am using vs2010 really only as an IDE, we do compile our code in cygwin with a Makefile system.  I don't know if it might be a problem for intellisense?

But then, I discovered an Enhanced IntelliSense feature with Visual Assist X, installed it and *voilà!* Intellisense magically starts to work really really well! (+ all cool feature of VAssistX indeed)

Soon as I disable VAssistX, IntelliSense stops working (always having this *Troubleshooting IntelliSense in C++ Projects*)

Any idea why IntelliSense not working without VAssistX?  (I am not sure my compagnie is willing to pay 250$ bucks)

thanks

Comment: That tomato completely *replaces* the VS IntelliSense engine.  If your productivity isn't worth 250 bucks then surely you'll have lots of time to find out why the VS engine has a problem with your code.

Comment: @HansPassant On their website, that was written "Enhanced Intellisense", so, I thought that they did a wrapper around Microsoft IntelliSense, or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

When your project is a pure native C++ project it should work. Intellisense support for C++/CLI was removed in Visual Studio 2010. See this link from the Microsoft [website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx)

Comment: Our code is C++ only, plus some C files.  Part of the code is using MFC, some parts using win32 api.  We are also using a bunch of 3rd party such as boost, Qt, ace, etc...

Comment: In Micrsoft Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense should be back, maybe it is possible to start working with the 2012 edition?